# Updating a table with missing records from another table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a query that returns records from the LEFT of the EXCEPT that are not on the right query;

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.Product
EXCEPT
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.WorkOrder;
```

Lets say there are 6 records returned (there are 6 records in Production.Product table, that are not in Production.WorkOrder)

How would I write the query to update the 6 records into Production.WorkOrder table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into workorder (productid)
select productid from product where productid not in (select productid from workorder)
```

This will insert into workorder all the productid's in the product table that aren't already in workorder.

Comment: I swear, one day I will reply with code that's syntaxtually correct first time. Cheers Stobor.

Comment: if there is any chance of having null in the subquery, instead of (select productid from workorder)
use (select productid from workorder where productid IS NOT NULL)

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a left join, like this:

```
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
SELECT p.ProductID
  FROM Production.Product p
  LEFT
  JOIN Production.WorkOrder wo
    ON p.ProductID = wo.ProductID
 WHERE wo.ProductID IS NULL;
```

This will return all the ProductID values from Product that do not appear in WorkOrder. The problem with the other answer (WHERE NOT IN) is that the sub-query will execute once/row, and if the tables are large, this will be really slow. A LEFT JOIN will only execute once, and then SQL will match the rows up - on a small table, there won't be much difference in practice, but on a larger table or in a production database, the difference will be immense.

Answer (score 0):

Just turn your query into an INSERT?

```
INSERT INTO Production.WorkOrder(ProductID, ...)
SELECT ProductID, ...
FROM Production.Product
EXCEPT
SELECT ProductID 
FROM Production.WorkOrder;
```